# service Restart=on-failure?

Tags: server, services, restart

When I tried adding "Restart=on-failure" to my .service (which simply launches an application), I got an error where it said this wasn't allowed.  Currently, it is Type=oneshot ( I also tried "simple") - which one should I use? thanks in advance!

**Edit:** added the .service code

```
[Unit]
Description=runs the app
After=multi-user.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/root/myApp/myApp.x86_64
Restart=on-failure

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

**EDIT2:** "hopefully working" version

```
[Unit]
Description=runs the app
After=multi-user.target

[Service]
Type=simple
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=3
ExecStart=/root/myApp/myApp.x86_64


[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: Place the `Restart` line on top of `ExecStart` line and retry

Comment: I also suggest you add a restart time of `RestartSec=3` or more

Comment: added it on top of ExecStart ,still says "Service has Restart= setting other than no, which isn't allowed for Type=oneshot services. Refusing."

Comment: What you should use (`oneshot` or `simple`) depends on your executable. `oneshot` is for _fire-and-forget_ programs. They get started and systemd doesn't care whether the run or not. So `Restart`is not allowed for them. `simple` is for programs that run and don't return until they are stopped. See [here](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html#Type=) for details.

Comment: Only you can tell how `/root/myApp/myApp.x86_64` behaves. According to its behaviour you must pick the correct [`Type=`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html#Type=) setting in the unit file. What happens when you start `myApp.x86_64` from the shell? Do you immediately get a prompt and the program does something in background? Does it spawn children? Then `forking` might me suitable. Or is your shell blocked until `myApp.x86_64` ends? Then `simple` seems appropriate.

Comment: yay, seems to be working now! Placing the restart code above ExecStart and changing it to simple did the trick - will have to wait a while to see how it performs though

Comment: The order of the keywords is irrelevant. It's just that `Restart` isn't applicable for `Type=oneshot`.

Answer (score 0):

This has since been "fixed" with systemd [v244-rc1](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/commit/d727acb6505743098aa1c8bb1c4c473b5fab1379).